# How to prevent caching in Silverlight 5 OOB app

Tags: silverlight, caching

I am downloading a zip file from the server when my Silverlight 5 OOB app boots. However if the download fails and I delete the partially downloaded zip file and try to download again I am sent the same part downloaded cached file over and over again. I see no way of turning the cache off in OOB applications. Can someone offer advice on how to disable or modify caching for Silverlight 5 OOB apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had similar problem in our Silverlight App - in the end, we couldn't change OOB behavior, caching is some low level feature. We worked around it by adding some random query to Url, like

```
string url = FileUrl + "?" + randomString;
```

It makes application think it's a different file.